# Load Current year(Instead of 1900) in Flex DateField when tab out for partially entered date

Tags: apache-flex, datefield

In Flex Date Field i have entered partial date like below

12/15/

12-15-

then date is loaded as 12/15/1900 for the above both cases when focusing out from flex DateField.

but i would like to load entered date with current year instead of 1900(Eg : 12/15/2013).

kindly anyone give me succession to load date with current year.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add eventlistener to datachange, and

```
if (date.year==1900) date.year = new Date().year;
```

Comment: Thanks csomakk. 
i have done with below piece of code
if(enteredDate.fullYear == 1900)      enteredDate.fullYear = currentDate.fullYear;